# Parallel Processing via multiprocessing.Process() subclass

Tags: python, html, multithreading, python-multiprocessing

Here's the layout of my program:

Some processes are dedicated to fetching, BeautifulSoup-ing, and encoding (since BeautifulSoup objects can't be pickled) HTML from a long list of URLs. This HTML is `put()` into a `multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()`. A few more, separate, processes `get()` from the queue, re-BeautifulSoup and parse the HTML, and fill a local dictionary w/ some data. The dictionary is then passed onto another queue—where a dedicated thread writes them, as rows, to a file.

I'm creating processes like this:

```
numProcesses = 6
numGetProcesses = 3

# Get HTML
getProcesses = []
for ii in range(numGetProcesses):
    newProcess = GetHTML(urlInputQ, htmlOutputQ)
    getProcesses.append(newProcess)
    newProcess.start()    

# Parse HTML
parseProcesses = []
for ii in range(numProcesses - numGetProcesses)
    newProcess = ParseHTML(htmlOutputQ, dataOutputQ)
    parseProcesses.append(newProcess)
    newProcess.start()
```

Then, in the case that the `GetHTML` processes finish their job before the `ParseHTML` processes, I [think I] terminate them, and create new `ParseHTML` processes:

```
for process in getProcesses: process.join() # Wait for HTML
# Dedicate newly freed CPU to parsing
print('Redistributing wealth...')
for ii in range(numGetProcesses):
    oldProcess = getProcesses.pop()
    oldProcess.terminate()
    newProcess = csdb.ParseHTML(htmlOutputQ, dataOutputQ)
    parseProcesses.append(newProcess)
    newProcess.start()
```

I expect this to, at first, dedicate 3 processes towards fetching HTML and 3 processes towards parsing HTML. Then, when the HTML-getting is completed, there should be 6 processes parsing HTML. Two issues arise, and I think what may be causing them is a misunderstanding on my end of things:

1) When I change `numGetProcesses` to 1 or 5, I see no difference in total program speed (with about 1000 URLs, it finishes at around 3 minutes).

2) I also see no difference in how long it takes the HTML-get and HTML-parse queues to empty

3) The message "Redistributing wealth..." *always* pops up seconds before the `ParseHTML` processes completely empty their queue. That is, the `GetHTML` processes (whether there be 1 or 5) are finishing at the same time, and at the same time relative to the `ParseHTML` processes.

It seems to me as if there's a fixed number of processes running each function regardless of what numbers I set or how many processes I start. Does anyone have any ideas?

---

Sorry I can't include a full working code. It is much too large. Here, though, is what the `GetHTML` class looks like. The `ParseHTML` class is set up similarly, but does a *lot* more:

```
class GetHTML(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, inputQ, outputQ):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.inputQ = inputQ
        self.outputQ = outputQ
        self.data = df_base.copy()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            for key in self.data.keys(): self.data[key] = None
            info = self.inputQ.get()
            if info == "die": break
            self.data['id'] = info[1]
            self.data['date'] = info[2]
            uncookedHTML = CookSoup(info[0])
            encodedHTML = uncookedHTML.encode('utf-8')
            self.outputQ.put([self.data, encodedHTML])
            self.inputQ.task_done()
```

**CookSoup(url)**:

```
ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0 (compatible;)' #For User-Agent header
def CookSoup(url):
    request = urllib2.Request(url) # Requests URL
    request.add_header('User-Agent', ua) # Adds User Agent
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request) # Opens URL
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response) # Creates soup
    response.close() #Closes file
    return soup #Returns the HTML
```

Comment: "The message "Redistributing wealth..." always pops up seconds before the ParseHTML processes completely empty their queue." How can you tell? Does the ParseHTML class have diagnostic `print` statements? If so, it's possible that it's just buffer weirdness, where ParseHTML's `print` executes before the main process' does, but the main process' `print` gets rendered to screen first anyway.

Comment: Yeah. Just for debugging purposes, the `ParseHTML` class prints something every time it finishes a page. I'll mess around with flushing the buffer and see if that helps anything